# Printing CGridView - Yii

Tags: php, printing, yii, cgridview

I am trying to get my CGridView printed by a printer on a button.
**My View**

```
<p align="right">
        <?php 

            echo CHtml::link('New Job',array('create'),array('class'=>'btn btn-info'));
            echo CHtml::link('Print',array('print'),array('class'=>'btnPrint btn btn-info', 'style'=>'margin-left: 10px;'));
        ?>
    </p>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'job-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$jobs->search(),
    'filter'=>$jobs,
...)); ?>
```

**My Controller**

```
public function actionPrint() {
        $d = $_SESSION['all'];
        $this->renderPartial('print',array('d'=>$d),false,true);
}
```

**My model**

```
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('date',$this->date,true);
        $criteria->compare('department_id',$this->department_id);
        $criteria->compare('section_id',$this->section_id);
        $criteria->compare('team_id',$this->team_id);
        $criteria->compare('created_date',$this->created_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('updated_date',$this->updated_date,true);

        $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination'=>false,
        ));
        $_SESSION['all'] = $data;

        $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',
                        Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
        $_SESSION['limited'] = $data;

        return $data;
    }
```

**My view (print.php)**

```
<div id="summary">
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Job No.</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Team</th>
    </tr>  
    <?php   
    $i=1;
    foreach($d->data as $item)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->departmentsdep->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->departmentssec->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->departmentstea->name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

But using the above code i am receiving an error of Undefined index: all
How will this work.

Comment: where have you declared  $_SESSION['all']? You are using it in your model but you have not defined it.

Comment: Yii::app()->session['all']. what about adding this line? have you tried this?

Comment: similarly you can use it like $d=Yii::app()->session['var']

Comment: @RafayZiaMir It worked, but no i am getting Trying to get property of non-object for foreach.

Comment: bcz "->" is used to access the property of object not an array. as data is an array index so you can access as Yiiapp()->session['all']['data']. If this gives error then try to debug session. write CVarDumper::Dump(Yiiapp()->session['all'],100,true), die(), It will show the contents of session array. then post the results (in your question) you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Yii::app()->session['all']
```

instead of accessing the $_SESSION directly

Comment: It worked, but now i am getting Trying to get property of non-object for foreach.

Comment: That's because the assignment in the controller is being set before the search method is being called, try to call the search before the assignment in the controller and see what happens.